# Limit points and successors

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading Classic Set Theory by Derek Goldrei. In Exercise 7.12, the author asks to prove the following:

Let $<_X$ strictly order $X$ and suppose that the element $c$ of $X$ is neither a minimum element of X nor a successor. Then $c$ is a limit point.

Here's my counterexample for it:
Let $\mathbb{N}$ have the usual strict order relation $<$. Let us consider $a$ to be an arbitrary symbol. We can now view $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ a \}$ to be strictly ordered by $<$. Now $a$ is neither a minimum nor a successor nor a limit point of $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ a\}$.

It seems the exercise should add " strictly linearly order" to make it correct. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Evidently Goldrei means that $<_X$ is a strict linear order. Your $a$ would have to be added at the end in order to satisfy the hypothesis, and in that case it’s a limit point of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Goldrei doesn't make any explicit mention of this though. He talks about "strict partial order" and "strict linear order" in definitions. Is the notion of limit point useful in "strict partial order"? I ask this because Goldrei talks about limit points for "strict orders" only.

Comment: In some partial orders it can make sense when the topology is suitable defined, but it’s really natural only in linear orders, where it’s always applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be a strict *linear* order, and like Brian I think it's clear from chosen symbols and context. Using $<$ for strict partial (non-linear) orders is quite rare, I think.